# Blender Cycles Smoke not showing up

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So, all I've done is quick smoke, then adjusted the temperature difference, and then adjusted the smoke domain. Now the smoke won't show up at all. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: P.S. How do I add a blender file?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It works for me. Did you bake it?

Comment: Not yet. Oops. But now I have the issue that it is colliding like half a unit away from the wall, so it looks kinda dumb.

Comment: In one corner of the domain you can see a little cube, that shows the resolution. Probably it's pritty low, you have to increase it (cube will be smaller). Use as small domain as you can.

Comment: If you want to make mist, it's a built-in function in Blender. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxNeMMZs_sM